# Chrome won't allow download of file opened via Chrome Extension's Javascript window.open(URL)

Tags: google-chrome, download, javascript, extension

I have a Chrome extension which offers buttons, which when clicked perform a windows.open("url") command.  This part works fine, and I get a new tab when clicked, with the correct URL.  But Chrome won't let me download this file.  When the file is from a Google drive, I get the message:

```
drive.google.com is blocked
drive.google.com refused to connect.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

If instead I point to a file in my github, it shows the file like normal, and it has a download button, but the download button doesn't do anything when clicked.

But when I click my button, and in the new tab that appears, if I copy that URL and paste it into a new tab, it downloads just fine - whether it's from the Google drive or not, whether it's a PDF or not.

I've tried from Mac and Windows, and on a couple of different computers.

Chrome offers to open the file in a Connected App - when I try with "Text Editor", it shows me the file, and has a Download button, which is active, but clicking that button still doesn't download the file.

I have looked through a lot of Chrome security settings, but haven't found anything which will enable download the file directly from the initial tab.

What I want is to be able to download the file that is opened in the new tab, using the browser's normal download button.

---

To reproduce, add the [BBOAlert extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bboalert/bjgihidachainhhhilkeemegdhehnlcf) (I am piggybacking on this one).  Then go to the [Bridgebase](https://www.bridgebase.com/v3/) site, create a free account, and log in.  On the right-hand side, click the BBOalert tab.  This will bring up a blue panel.  Copy [this URL from my github](https://github.com/Rick-Wilson/Bridge-Dealer-Scripts/blob/main/Bridge%20Lesson%20Hands%20Menu).  While this is in your clipboard, click the Data... pulldown menu from the blue panel, and select "Paste(New)".  This tells the extension to load the file from the clipboard.  Now click the Shortcuts menu from the blue panel.  You should see several buttons, in orange and blue.  Click the blue "Play of the Hand in the 21st Century" button.  This will expand more buttons.  Click the NS button to the right of "Making a Plan".  This should open 2 tabs, one for a PDF and one for a .LIN file (a short text file).  On the tab for the .LIN file, I get a message "No preview available", but there's a blue Download button.  Click that button.  For me, I get an error message.  What I would like is for that file to be downloaded when I click that button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this work from an Incognito window? You might need to enable this extension in `chrome://extensions/` for Incognito mode.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example: Provide a link to the extension in the Chrome Web Store and also a link to a page with exact reproduction steps.

Comment: @harrymc I have enabled the extension in Incognito mode, and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Such a problem is usually caused by conflicting multiple accounts for Google Drive, but this should really be resolved in Incognito mode. Try perhaps to clear the Chrome cache and cookies.

Comment: @harrymc I tried incognito mode and I get the same error.  I also get similar behavior when my target file is hosted on my github - that's not using Google Drive access rights.  I have also tried clearing the Chrome cache and cookies and no improvement.

Comment: @DanielB I have added detailed instructions on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't download from Drive or github while going through this extension, but have no problem when not using it? If so, I suggest to use the Chrome DevTools to analyze the differences between both types of calls.

Comment: @harrymc - Yes, the files download fine if I start by pasting the URL into a new tab.  But when the tab is opened by the extension, it shows a preview of the file (for the PDF), but gives an error when I try to download it.  When I just look at the URL in the tab, there is no visible difference between the two cases.  I'll take a look at the Chrome DevTools and see if I can glean anything.